# Where does the integral go to in the field decomposition for Klein Gordon Field?

Tags: field-theory, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I am following Peskin Schroeder's book on QFT. In Chapter 2, page 20, they propose expanding the Klein Gordon Field in terms of the Fourier modes:

$$\phi (x,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3p e^{ipx}\phi(p,t)$$

Plugging this into the Klein Gordon Equation gets us:

$$(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu+m^2)\phi(x,t)=(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu+m^2)\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3p e^{ipx}\phi(p,t)=0$$
$$=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+|p|^2+m^2)\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3p e^{ipx}\phi(p,t)=0$$
That part is clear, but now, In equation 2.21 they just drop the integral altogether and write:
$$=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+|p|^2+m^2)\phi(p,t)=0$$
What is the reason for dropping the integral? I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: Since $(\partial_t^2+p^2+m^2)\phi(p,\,t)$ has $3$-dimensional inverse Fourier transform $0$ for all $x$, it's the FT of $0$, so is $0$.

Comment: As $\vec{p}$ is your integration variable, it cannot stand outside of the integral. Your formula should read $\int d^3 p \, e^{i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}} (\partial_t^2 +\vec{p}^2 +m^2) \phi(\vec{p},t) =0$ implying $(\partial_t^2 + \vec{p}^2 +m^2) \phi(\vec{p},t)=0$ for the reason explained by J.G. in the above comment.

Comment: I Understand, Thank you very much!